# Masking different input formats to defined date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue 3 application with a simple input field. Users shall use this field for inputting a date string in different formats while the field automatically applies an input mask.

The following inputs shall be available to the user and all of them shall result in `DD.MM.YYYY`:

1. `12031956` --> `12.03.1956`
2. `120356` --> `12.03.1956`
3. `12.03.1956` --> `12.03.1956`

For this, I created the following watcher:

```js
const dateString = ref('');

watch(dateString, (value) => {
  dateString.value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
    .replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/g, '$1.$2.$3')
    .substring(0, 10);
});
```

This works fine for #1 but I don't have any idea how I could extend this, so that also input formats #2 and #3 are supported.

Comment: Different cases can be handled by string length.

Comment: 56->1956 needs to be separately handled because dates aren't limited to one century. Means that you have to parse a value to proper date at some point instead of manipulating strings.